# NavigationManager does not works as expected?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

If I create a page in Shared - LoginPage.razor :

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;


<button @onclick="onBtnClick"> sfsdf</button>

@code
{
    public void onBtnClick()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo( "/Error" );
    }
}
```

in App.razor change DefaultLayout to the new page above:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(LoginPage)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(LoginPage)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Then create a page inside Pages. let say ErrorPage.razor :

```
@page "/Error"
<h3>ErrorPage</h3>

@code 
{
}
```

And if I run the app and click the button the page should be changing to Error page, but only the URL is changing.

- how can I switch to Error page ?

Comment: you mean your initial page is LoginPage (you created) instead MainLayout. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have missed @Body tag from LoginPage bootstrap component, which will load your error component on button click.

**LoginPage.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<button @onclick="onButtonClick">Go To Error Page</button>

<div class="bodyLoginPage">
    @Body
</div>

@code{
    public void onButtonClick()
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Error");
    }
}
```

Hope, it will help. Thanks

Comment: Thank You @Rahul, this seems like is one of the issue, but the page which is going to the Body now does not replace the content of the LoginPage as i have expected to happen.

Comment: Glad, your first problem solved. If you're happy with answer, please accept this answer. About your second question.. yes, it won't replace the content of login page. It will inject your component HTML into body tag only. because your main page content outside of body.

Comment: I see. Probably this will leads me to another quesion i have to ask :)